# Can I handle iterators with template?

Tags: c++, vector, iterator

I'm a newbie doing an exercise from "C++ Primer 5th edition",p110, which goes:
Write a program to print the size and contents of the vectors as following.

(a) `vector<int> v1;`

(b) `vector<int> v2(10);`

(f) `vector<string> v6{10};`

(g) `vector<string> v7{10, "hi"};`

Can I use a template function to process both string and int vectors above?
I wrote a function like this:

```
    template<class t>
    void check_vector(vector<t> *_v)
    {
        if(_v->begin() == _v->end())
        {
            cout << "the vector is empty\n";
        }
        else
        {
            int i=0;

            for(vector<t>::iterator it = _v->begin(); it != _v->end(); it++)   //error.
            {
                cout << *it;
                i++;
            }
            cout << "\nthe size is : "
                   <<i
                     <<"\n";
        }
    }
```

The error generated is **need 'typename' before 'std::vector::iterator' because 'std::vector' is a dependent scope.**

Is it possible to do so?
If so, how should I fix the code?
Thx.

Comment: What is "vector v1;" supposed to mean?

Comment: So put it there! Usually you can trust the compiler, if it's giving you such hints.

Comment: v1 is just an empty vector.@aschepler

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The compiler very clearly tells you to write

```
for(typename vector<t>::iterator it = _v->begin(); it != _v->end(); it++)
 // ^^^^^^^^
```

to fix it. Did you try that?

At least

```
typedef typename vector<t>::iterator It;
for(It it = _v->begin(); it != _v->end(); it++)
```

should work.

Comment: Hi .I tried int and string puting there. Still didn't work..and got the error: invalid declaration of 'std::vector<t>::iterator'

Comment: Why? It's not about putting string or int, but prefixing the iterator declaration with **`typename`**

Comment: _Those who are audacious enough to ask, **never** will be the stupid ones. Those who never ask are the ones left behind dumb._